# Print calculation sheet (interactive form) in IE 11 with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have different interactive forms and I am looking for a pure JavaScript solution to print a section of the page on click. So each page would have a button "Click to print" and it should open a new page ready for print.  I tried many solution and some of them work great except in IE11.

Some of my forms are complex but to keep it simple, here is a simple example of the code I am trying to use:

```
<div id='DivIdToPrint'>
<p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>

  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br><br>
  Gender: <br />
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br><br>
  </div>
```

`<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printDiv();'>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv() {
   var divToPrint = document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint').innerHTML;
   var newWin = window.open();
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
</script>
```

Two issues: 
 1. I cannot get the value of each form item printed and
 2. This solution is not working in IE11.

Could someone help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Filling the form doesn't modify the html markup, nor will it change the `value` attribute in actual markup. So you can't get the value with `.innerHTML`. If you want the html with the new value just set the attribute to the new value.
2. To make sure the script's output actually shows up in the other window, we should use `document.close()` after writing the content.

You could check my demo, it can work well in IE and other broswers:

```
<div id='DivIdToPrint'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br><br>
    Gender: <br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="aa" value="a"> A<br>
    <input type="radio" name="aa" value="b"> B<br>
    <input type="radio" name="aa" value="c"> C<br><br>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printDiv();'>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv() {
        //Set attribute to new value
        var inputs, index;
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (index = 0; index < inputs.length - 1; ++index) {
            var fieldValue = inputs[index].value;
            inputs[index].setAttribute('value', fieldValue);               
        }
        var radios, i;
        radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            radios[i].setAttribute('checked', true);
        }
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint').innerHTML;
        var newWin = window.open();
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint);
        newWin.document.close(); //Close after writing content
        newWin.focus();
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested your code and it works in different browsers, but for some reason it's not working in IE 11. When I click on Print, it actually opens a Windows Explorer instead. Another thing ... is there a way to make javascript to dynamically set the value to all form items, instead of manually modify a javascript to each form? I have over 1000 forms (most of them very different) ...and I have no choice but to use IE 11 at the moment.

Comment: I modified my code, the function can set value dynamically by using `for` loop. If you have other types of `input`, just add other `for` loop like the code. And I'm a little confused about "not working in IE11". When I test in my side, it actually opens a new page and a print dialog [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vikwn.gif). And I'm using [IE 11 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4gka.png) 11.116.18362.0 on Windows 10. You could update your IE 11 to the latest version and try it again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems to be working now.

Comment: Cheers! You could mark the answer as accepted or post your own solution and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I did mark your answer as accepted solution, but got this message "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Thanks again for you help!